# Yet another 'not declared in this scope' issue when it is declared

Tags: c++, scoping

I'm currently working on a card program for a class andI'm running into an issue where the compiler is telling me that things are not being declared in the scope when they are and some things are not declared at all when it is. Here is the code:

**Card.h:**

```
#ifndef _CARD_H
#define _CARD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum RANK{Joker, Ace = 1, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King}
enum SUIT{Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades}

class Card
{
private:
    //Rank and Suit variables for all cards
    int rank;
    int suit;

public:
    //Constructors
    Card();
    Card(int r, int s);

    //Getters
    int getRank();
    int getSuit();

    //Setters
    void setRank(int r);
    void setSuit(int s);

    //toString
    string toString();
};

#endif
```

**Card.cpp:**

```
#ifndef _CARD_H
#define _CARD_H
#include "Card.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Default constructor
Card::Card()
{
    rank=Joker;
    suit=Clubs;
}

//Constructor
Card::Card(int r, int s)
{
    rank = r;
    suit = s;
}

//Getters for rank and suit
int Card::getRank()
{
    return rank;
}
int Card::getSuit()
{
    return suit;
}

//Setters for rank and suit
void Card::setRank(int r)
{
    rank = r;
}
void Card::setSuit(int s)
{
    suit = s;
}

//toString function for output
string Card::toString()
{
    string tempstring = ""; //list of if-else statements for what to add to the string that gets printed
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        tempstring += "Joker";
        goto stringEnd; //sends the process to the end of the list if rank is Joker so it doesn't attempt to add a suit to the card toString
    }
    else if (rank == 1)
        tempstring += "Ace of ";
    else if (rank == 2)
        tempstring += "Two of ";
    else if (rank == 3)
        tempstring += "Three of ";
    else if (rank == 4)
        tempstring += "Four of ";
    else if (rank == 5)
        tempstring += "Five of ";
    else if (rank == 6)
        tempstring += "Six of ";
    else if (rank == 7)
        tempstring += "Seven of ";
    else if (rank == 8)
        tempstring += "Eight of ";
    else if (rank == 9)
        tempstring += "Nine of ";
    else if (rank == 10)
        tempstring += "Ten of ";
    else if (rank == 11)
        tempstring += "Jack of ";
    else if (rank == 12)
        tempstring += "Queen of ";
    else if (rank == 13)
         tempstring += "King of ";
    if (suit == 0)
        tempstring += "Clubs";
    else if (suit == 1)
        tempstring += "Diamonds";
    else if (suit == 2)
        tempstring += "Hearts";
    else if (suit == 3)
        tempstring += "Spades";
    stringEnd:
    return tempstring;
}

#endif
```

I'm not sure why it's not compiling right. Everything seems alright to me.

Comment: This isn’t the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_CARD_H`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Answer (score 5):

You should not use `#include` guards in a `.cpp` file. Your `.h` file is basically not being parsed at all because `_CARD_H` is already defined.

Answer (score 0):

1. Missing semicolons at the end of enum declarations.
2. Includes are not needed in Card.cpp except #include "Card.h"

So, Card.h will be like

```
#ifndef _CARD_H
#define _CARD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum RANK{Joker, Ace = 1, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King};
enum SUIT{Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades};

class Card{
private:
    //Rank and Suit variables for all cards
    int rank;
    int suit;
public:
    //Constructors
    Card();
    Card(int r, int s);

    //Getters
    int getRank();
    int getSuit();

    //Setters
    void setRank(int r);
    void setSuit(int s);

    //toString
    string toString();
};

#endif
```

And Card.cpp will be like

```
#include "Card.h"
//Default constructor
Card::Card()
{
    rank=Joker;
    suit=Clubs;
}

//Constructor
Card::Card(int r, int s)
{
    rank = r;
    suit = s;
}

//Getters for rank and suit
int Card::getRank()
{
    return rank;
}
int Card::getSuit()
{
    return suit;
}

//Setters for rank and suit
void Card::setRank(int r)
{
    rank = r;
}
void Card::setSuit(int s)
{
    suit = s;
}

//toString function for output
string Card::toString()
{
    string tempstring = ""; //list of if-else statements for what to add to the string that gets printed
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        tempstring += "Joker";
        goto stringEnd; //sends the process to the end of the list if rank is Joker so it doesn't attempt to add a suit to the card toString
    }
    else if (rank == 1)
        tempstring += "Ace of ";
    else if (rank == 2)
        tempstring += "Two of ";
    else if (rank == 3)
        tempstring += "Three of ";
    else if (rank == 4)
        tempstring += "Four of ";
    else if (rank == 5)
        tempstring += "Five of ";
    else if (rank == 6)
        tempstring += "Six of ";
    else if (rank == 7)
        tempstring += "Seven of ";
    else if (rank == 8)
        tempstring += "Eight of ";
    else if (rank == 9)
        tempstring += "Nine of ";
    else if (rank == 10)
        tempstring += "Ten of ";
    else if (rank == 11)
        tempstring += "Jack of ";
    else if (rank == 12)
        tempstring += "Queen of ";
    else if (rank == 13)
         tempstring += "King of ";
    if (suit == 0)
        tempstring += "Clubs";
    else if (suit == 1)
        tempstring += "Diamonds";
    else if (suit == 2)
        tempstring += "Hearts";
    else if (suit == 3)
        tempstring += "Spades";
    stringEnd:
    return tempstring;
}
```

It should compile fine.